# JTable with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

Is there any way to enable horizontal scroll-bar whenever necessary?

The situation was as such: I've a `JTable`, one of the cells, stored a long length of data. Hence, I need to have horizontal scroll-bar.

Anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

First, add your `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane` and set the policy for the existence of scrollbars:

```
new JScrollPane(myTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Then, indicate that your JTable must not auto-resize the columns by setting the `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` mode:

```
myJTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Comment: In Netbeans, the JScrollPane with JTable intial components have been set up in a method which is cannot be modified.

Any idea to solve this? I tried putting in the method, however, the table disappeared once I put above code in a button handler for testing purpose.

Comment: @MrCooL could you edit your original post to show your Java code?

Comment: okay, it works finally with some manipulations in Netbeans...

Thanks romaintaz! ;)

Comment: Single-argument constructor of `JScrollPane` sets `*_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` so there's no need to specify that.

Comment: save me a lott of times

Comment: I have used both lines given in this answer in my code, but I see xyz.... . That is truncation of original line in Jtable and no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @MrCooL could you please share how to achieve this in Netbeans?

Answer (score 12):

Set the `AutoResizeMode` to `OFF` in the properties of the `jTable`

Answer (score 4):

For reference, here's a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the [accepted approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452758/230513). Moreover,

- You can adjust the size of individual columns as shown in [*Setting and Changing Column Widths*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953972/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31977754/230513).
- You can adjust the overall size of the enclosing scroll pane as shown in [*Implementing a Scrolling-Savvy Client*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974131/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318673/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
            private static final int N = 32;

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return N;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return N;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                return "R" + rowIndex + ":C" + colIndex;
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        };
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works:

> table.setAutoscrolls(true);

Answer (score 0):

I had to do several things to get mine working

1. Set `autoResize` to `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`.
2. Set `preferredSize` on JTable to `null`.
3. Set `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` on `JScrollPane` to AS_NEEDED.