# Scroll to last added row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtable

I use a HashMap to fill a JTable, which is more or less continuously updated:

> public Map< Long, MyObject > tableData = new HashMap< Long, MyObject >();

Every time a new element is added to the map the table model is notified:

```
tableData.put(id, anObject);

AbstractTableModel atm = (AbstractTableModel)model;
atm.fireTableDataChanged();
```

In Addition I have a TableRowSorter which sorts the rows according to a specific criteria:

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
.
.
.
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

My goal is that the (vertical) scrollbar always jumps to the last added row, which can be somwhere in the mid
of the table because of the sorter probably using this:

```
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(row,0, true));
```

The problem is I do not know the index of the row :) Where can I hook in to get this index?

Comment: unrelated: a) never-ever fire a event on behalf of the model, instead implement a custom model with with modifying api that fulfills its notification contract itself b) always fire the most narrow event that's possible, f.i. an update/insert (vs. the shotgun dataChanged) c) if your rowSorter is just the plain core version, consider using table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true) instead of creating and setting it manually

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scrolling to a newly inserted row in a potentially sorted table involves

- listening to changes in the table model
- converting the rowIndex of the event (it is in model coordiates) to view coordinates
- scrolling to the view position

In code:

```
final JTable table = new JTable();
TableModelListener l = new TableModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        if (TableUtilities.isInsert(e)) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int viewRow = table.convertRowIndexToView(e.getFirstRow());
                    table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(viewRow, 0, true));    
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(l);
```

Two important aspects:

- your model implemenation must fire the correct event, that is a insert, not a dataChanged
- invoking both index conversion and scrolling guarantees that the table (which is listening to the model as well) has updated all internal state according to the model change.

Comment: f.i. in a listener to the model

Comment: @kleopatra hm, but in the listener I do not know the modelRow

Comment: +1 for `convert*`; more examples of scrolling to the last row may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).

Comment: @user1703554 your model implementation _must_ return a stable order, that is f.i. it must know where in the sequence it reports to the outside world a new row is added and then fire that index, independent of the underlying data structure. Otherwise its not a valid implemenation.