# Large gap between JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane, preferredsize

The below is on the way to providing the results I am looking for, but unfortunately when this displays there is a large gap between tables on each page. It is so that I can only fit two of them on the screen per tab (with just two rows per table).

```
private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new JLabel("Test"));
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

class ResultsPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private ArrayList<Venue> venueList;
    private Timer timer;
    QueueItem[] queue;
    Reporter reporter;
    private JPanel resultsPane1;
    private JPanel resultsPane2;
    private JTable[] table1;
    private JTable[] table2;
    private int totalItems;
    public String[] page1ColumnNames = {
        "Name",
        "Wins",
        "Losses",
        "Draws",
        "Win %",
        "Avg Turns"};
    public String[] page2ColumnNames = {
        "Name",
        "H%Total",
        "H%inRange",
        "KO/F rcvd",
        "KO/F Infl",
        "HChances",
        "HitsTotal",
        "Wounds Inflicted",
        "Wounds Received"};
    public String[][] page1Data = new String[2][6];
    public String[][] page2Data = new String[2][9];

    public void initResults() {

        timer = new Timer(500, this);
        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException d) {
            System.err.println("Caught : InterruptedException" + d.getMessage());
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public ResultsPanel(QueueItem[] queueItems) {
        super();
        totalItems = 0;
        queue = queueItems;


        for (QueueItem a : queue) {
            if (a != null) {
                totalItems++;
            }
        }

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        resultsPane1 = new JPanel();
        resultsPane2 = new JPanel();
        resultsPane1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resultsPane1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        resultsPane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resultsPane2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        table1 = new JTable[totalItems];
        table2 = new JTable[totalItems];
        for (int b = 0; b < totalItems; b++) {
            reporter = queue[b].reporter;
            generateData();
            table1[b] = new JTable(page1Data, page1ColumnNames);
            table2[b] = new JTable(page2Data, page2ColumnNames);
            resultsPane1.add(new JScrollPane(table1[b]));
            resultsPane2.add(new JScrollPane(table2[b]));
        }



        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(resultsPane1);
        JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(resultsPane2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Win/Loss", scrollPane1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Overall", scrollPane2);
        add(tabbedPane);

    }

    public void generateData() {
        double temp = 0;
        double avgTurns;
        double total;

        for (Integer a : reporter.numberOfTurns) {
            temp = temp + a;
        }
        avgTurns = 1.0 * temp / reporter.numberOfTurns.size();

        page1Data[0][0] = reporter.glad1.name;
        page1Data[0][1] = "" + reporter.gladTotalWins1;
        page1Data[0][2] = "" + reporter.gladTotalLosses1;
        page1Data[0][3] = "" + reporter.gladTotalDraws1;
        temp = (int) ((reporter.gladTotalWins1 * 100.0) / (reporter.gladTotalWins1 + reporter.gladTotalLosses1 + reporter.gladTotalDraws1));
        page1Data[0][4] = "" + temp + "%";
        page1Data[0][5] = "" + avgTurns;
        page1Data[1][0] = reporter.glad2.name;
        page1Data[1][1] = "" + reporter.gladTotalWins2;
        page1Data[1][2] = "" + reporter.gladTotalLosses2;
        page1Data[0][3] = "" + reporter.gladTotalDraws2;
        temp = (int) ((reporter.gladTotalWins2 * 100.0) / (reporter.gladTotalWins2 + reporter.gladTotalLosses2 + reporter.gladTotalDraws2));
        page1Data[1][4] = "" + temp + "%";
        page1Data[1][5] = "" + avgTurns;

        page2Data[0][0] = reporter.glad1.name;

        total = 0;
        for (double a : reporter.hitChancePercentOut1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        temp = 1.0 * total / reporter.hitChancePercentOut1.size();
        page2Data[0][1] = "" + temp;

        total = 0;
        for (double a : reporter.hitChancePercentIn1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        temp = 1.0 * total / reporter.hitChancePercentIn1.size();
        page2Data[0][2] = "" + temp;



        page2Data[1][0] = reporter.glad2.name;

        total = 0;
        for (double a : reporter.hitChancePercentOut2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        temp = 1.0 * total / reporter.hitChancePercentOut2.size();
        page2Data[1][1] = "" + temp;

        total = 0;
        for (double a : reporter.hitChancePercentIn2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        temp = 1.0 * total / reporter.hitChancePercentIn2.size();
        page2Data[1][2] = "" + temp;



        int deadCount2 = 0;
        int KOCount2 = 0;
        for (String a : reporter.endStatus2) {
            if (a.equals("DEAD")) {
                deadCount2++;
            } else if (a.equals("KO")) {
                KOCount2++;
            }

        }
        int deadCount1 = 0;
        int KOCount1 = 0;
        for (String a : reporter.endStatus1) {
            if (a.equals("DEAD")) {
                deadCount1++;
            } else if (a.equals("KO")) {
                KOCount1++;
            }

        }
        page2Data[0][3] = "" + KOCount1 + "/" + deadCount1;
        page2Data[1][3] = "" + KOCount2 + "/" + deadCount2;
        page2Data[0][4] = "" + KOCount2 + "/" + deadCount2;
        page2Data[1][4] = "" + KOCount1 + "/" + deadCount1;

        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.hitChances1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[0][5] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.hitTotals1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[0][6] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.woundsInflicted1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[0][7] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.woundsReceived1) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[0][8] = "" + total;
        total = 0;

        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.hitChances2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[1][5] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.hitTotals2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[1][6] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.woundsInflicted2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[1][7] = "" + total;
        total = 0;
        for (Integer a : reporter.woundsReceived2) {
            total = total + a;
        }
        page2Data[1][8] = "" + total;
        total = 0;

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }
}
```

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks

Edit: Edited to add full code per request... most of it is irrelevant to what is going on here. Also removed setPreferredSize, but still same result.

Edit 2:

[image]

FYI, the blank spot in "Draws" is unrelated.

Comment: you should show a SSCCE (not a ton of code which even you evaluate as unrelated ;-) Anyway, @trashgod is spot on, it's the rather arbitrary size that JTable.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize returns: override and let it return some reasonable value depending on the rowCount

Comment: `Venue`? `QueueItem`? `Reporter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absent a complete example, it's hard to be sure what you're seeing. Given that one should avoid [`setPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), note that `JTable` implements `Scrollable` and can calculate it's own preferred size. Unfortunately,  the arbitrary `Dimension` calculated may be causing the problem. Overriding `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to return a multiple of `getRowHeight()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513), may be a useful alternative.

Comment: +1 for hitting the nail spot on - the getPrefScrollable _is_ a nuisance, btw: JXTable does exactly that rowCount relative calculation. Note to myself: not yet optimal - should allow to optinally take actual rows up to a maximum into account)

Comment: It seems the consensus is that I need to do the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() override. Marking as accepted.

Comment: You may also want to look at the result returned by `BasicTableUI#getPreferredSize()`.