# Error adding Row into JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a `JButton` which, once it is pressed, adds a row into a `JTable`. I have tried to make this by implementing the following code.

```
columNames = new Vector<>();
columNames.addElement("Name");
columNames.addElement("CC");
columNames.addElement("Age");
columNames.addElement("PhoneNumber");
columNames.addElement("Date");
columNames.addElement("Amount$");

Object[] dataList = {"name", "cc", "age", "phone", "date", "amount"};

data = new DefaultTableModel(columNames, 0);
data.addRow(dataList);

table = new JTable(data);
JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollTable.setBounds(22, 78, 764, 177);
scrollTable.setViewportView(table);

//ActionListener method!.

if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Add client"))
{
    Object[] dataList = {"name", "cc", "age", "phone", "date", "amount"};
    data.addRow(dataList);

    DefaultTableModel defaut = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    defaut.addRow(dataList);
}
```

It throws `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:`-1`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your ActionListener appears to be trying to add the dataList array to the table model **twice**, once via the data object, once via the extracted table model -- why? Why not try to simply add it once?

Comment: If TrashGod's answer doesn't help you solve the problem, then please consider creating and posting a valid [mcve], a small self-contained program that demonstrates your problem, similar to what trashgod has already posted below.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i trying to adding twice cuz the second one is a Action listener wuich will add a new Row.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is referring to the redundant calls to `addRow()` in your `ActionListener`. Which one gives you the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the complete example below, your fragments appear to work correctly. The example may help you isolated the problem in your full code. In addition,

- Instead of `setBounds()`, override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to return a multiple of `getRowHeight()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17416278/230513), and `pack()` the enclosing window.
- See also  [*What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/230513)
- As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926148/error-adding-row-into-jtable/38926460#comment65209924_38926148), repeated failures to update the `TableModel` suggests that you may be referencing an unintended instance of an object.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926460/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private final Object[] dataList = {"name", "cc", "age", "phone", "date", "amount"};

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Vector columNames = new Vector<>();
        columNames.addElement("Name");
        columNames.addElement("CC");
        columNames.addElement("Age");
        columNames.addElement("Phone");
        columNames.addElement("Date");
        columNames.addElement("Amount$");
        DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(columNames, 0);
        data.addRow(dataList);
        JTable table = new JTable(data);
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollTable.setViewportView(table);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                data.addRow(dataList);
            }
        }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```