# Jtable no repaint

Tags: java, jtable, deserialization

Here i have a program which initialize a Jtable to later on if a user want update the data of TABLE they can make it by importing it.

```
Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<>();  //Uses this Dta instead of Desearilze.
            rowOne.addElement("Harry");
            rowOne.addElement("100414");
            rowOne.addElement("21");
            rowOne.addElement("239438"); 
            rowOne.addElement("24/24/23");
            rowOne.addElement("30000");

            Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<>();
            rowData.addElement(rowOne);

            columnNames = new Vector<>();
            columnNames.addElement("Name");
            columnNames.addElement("Cc");
            columnNames.addElement("Age");
            columnNames.addElement("Phone");
            columnNames.addElement("Date");
            columnNames.addElement("Amount");

          DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
          table = new JTable(model);

        scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollTable.setBounds(23, 77, 769, 242);
        scrollTable.setViewportView(table);

        contentPane.add(scrollTable);

        button.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("import"))
        {
            JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
            int i = file.showOpenDialog(this);

            if(i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File f = file.getSelectedFile();
                String filePath = f.getPath();

                try
                {

                    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
                    Vector vectorData = (Vector)input.readObject();
                    data = new DefaultTableModel(vectorData, columnNames);
                    table.setModel(data);
                    }
}
}
}
```

Problem is that when i import the data for the table the Jtable in GUI no change, how can i make it display?

Comment: Possible duplicate of your previous question not his topic: [*Error adding Row into JTable*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38926148/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To notify your JTable about changes of your data, use
[tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29):

```
table.setModel(data);
//add
data.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: Firing a `TableModelEvent` is the responsibility of the `TableModel`; `DefaultTableModel` fires the event for you, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38926460/230513).