# How to display a scrollbar to a table's last row programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have created a `JTable`, added it to the `JScrollpane` and added a method

```
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
  if ( getParent() instanceof JViewport ) {
    return ( ( (JViewport) getParent() ).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height );
  }
  return false;
}
```

I also added `table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(30, 0, true));`

However, the scrollbar is at the top of the table. Is there a way so that I can move it to end of the table always when opening a table?

Answer (score 3):

You may mean that you want the scrollbar's *indicator*, sometimes called the *thumb*, to move to the bottom of the scrollbar as needed. There's a complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513). In summary,

```
int last = table.getModel().getRowCount() - 1;
Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(last, 0, true);
table.scrollRectToVisible(r);
```

[image]

Comment: no i am not adding row at runtime.I am selecting some values from my GUI and it will be displayed in tabular format.I want always scrollbar at last row.how can i do it?

Comment: Do it exactly the same way in your constructor, _after_ you create your scroll pane, of course.