# how to resize JTable inside JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I want to resize JTable inside JTabbedPane, but i have no clue how to do that. currently my JTab only display JTable on default size.

[image]

currently my code is like this

```
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    Object rowData[][] = {
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3", "", "", "",
                    "", "" } };
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three",
            "", "", "", "" };
    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    tabbedPane.addTab("table", null, scrollPane, null);
```

here is my full code = [My Code](http://pastebin.com/FmKevtw3)

Comment: It's already is expanded the full size. You just need to add more rows. What you are seeing is the scoll pane's view port that is reserving space for the table. If rows are more than will fit in the view, you will see the scroll bars.

Comment: that mean you want empty rows ?

Comment: oh..is there any other way i can make the jtable fullscreen? if not maybe i can only just manually create table with Jlable..T.T

Comment: What do you mean full screen? The table is already the size of the tab. Even that empty space is part of the table.

Comment: actually i will put value on the table.

Comment: If you want you can add a bunch of empty rows, but that will just added unnecessary complexity when trying to insert data

Comment: oh..i see, so is there a way i can make the row fit the whole tab/table.. thanks you for your help

Comment: you can increase cell height

Comment: Personally, I would just leave everything the way it is. Let it function the way it's meant to

Comment: hmmm...ok i agree to your opinion..last question peeskillet, currently i add my scroll pane directly to JTab, is that proper? because on tutorial and other code usually they will add panel first to JTab.

Comment: should i add panel first then i add jscroll to that panel

Comment: You don't need to add a panel. Scroll pane is fine. Any container will do. Unless you want to add more than just the table to the tab, I wouldn't worry about putting the scroll pane into a panel first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can help you to set  row height of your table .

```
table.setRowHeight(anInteger);
```

In addition you know that with this code you can have your pleasant height of your jtabel:

```
int scrollPaneHeight = scrollPane.getHeight();
```

So you want every row has this height :

```
int spaceForRows = scrollPaneHeight -heightOfheaderOfTabel;

float rowH =(float) spaceForRows / (rowData.length );
```

But as you know when you re-size your jframe and consequently your scrollPane and your table can not  be full screen twice. So you most use a componentListener . So when your component is re-sizing your code calculate  rowH twice.
complete code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.setContentPane(tabbedPane);
    final Object rowData[][] = {
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "", "", "", "", "" },
            { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3", "", "", "",
                    "", "" } };
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three",
            "", "", "", "" };
    final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    tabbedPane.addTab("table", null, scrollPane, null);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    tabbedPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int scrollPaneHeight = scrollPane.getHeight();
            JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
            int heightOfheaderOfTabel = header.getHeight();
            int spaceForRows = scrollPaneHeight - heightOfheaderOfTabel;
            float rowH = (float) spaceForRows / (rowData.length);
            table.setRowHeight((int) rowH);

        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: It might be easier to override [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).

Answer (score 3):

The fixed size is because the default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, which uses the table's preferred size. Instead, use something like `GridLayout`, which fills the space available.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
```

Comment: Alos consider overridding [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).