# How to make java message dialog bigger?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, messagedialog

Im currently using the following code

```
tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
jTable2 = new JTable(tableModel);        
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(jTable2));
```

and when I execute it, the resulting size looks like below

[image]

How can I make message dialog bigger, so that we can see the column headings? I want to remove those '...'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `preferredSize` to the `JScrollPane` ?

Comment: yes its working now... why is that setSize is not working? but if I use setPreferredSize, its working? Thanks!

Comment: @IvanMatala See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone) for example/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. This is basically the ONE question every beginner will have someday with Swing.

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) or [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).