# JTable height calculation

Tags: java, swing, jtable

**Solution**

jtable.getHeight does not include header element

jtable.getRowHeight include margin

and the example has 15px actual height, not 14px

**More clear example**

```
RO 16
R1 16
R2 16
HEIGHT 48
INTERCELL java.awt.Dimension[width=1,height=1]
MARGIN 1
```

I have JTable with 3 rows. Each row is **16px**. And each row margin 1px.
So I suspect that table height should be 16 + 1 + 16 + 1 + 16 = 50px

BUT getHeight returns 48px

Also I did streenshot. Each row has **14px** height actually.

How how is it possible????

[Source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ezh/DOTFILES/master/PUBLIC/SO-34135994/TableExample.java)

[image: Visual representation]

```
    //headers for the table
    String[] columns = new String[] {
        "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate", "Part Time"
    };

    //actual data for the table in a 2d array
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
        {1, "John", 40.0, false },
        {2, "Rambo", 70.0, false },
        {3, "Zorro", 60.0, true },
    };

    //create table with data
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

    //add the table to the frame
    this.add(table);

    this.setTitle("Table Example");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("RO " + table.getRowHeight(0));
    System.out.println("R1 " + table.getRowHeight(1));
    System.out.println("R2 " + table.getRowHeight(2));
    System.out.println("HEIGHT " + table.getHeight());
    System.out.println("INTERCELL " + table.getIntercellSpacing());
    System.out.println("MARGIN " + table.getRowMargin());
}
```

---

**Original question**

I have simple test frame with jtable in the scroll pane.

The table minimum height is less than actual height.
header + rows < actual size

It is nonsense.

```
  val jtable = view.tableControl
  val headerHeight = jtable.getTableHeader.getHeight
  val rowsHeight = (0 until jtable.getRowCount()).foldLeft(0) { (heightAccumulator, counter) ⇒
    println("Row " + counter + " height " + jtable.getRowHeight(counter))
    jtable.getRowHeight(counter) + heightAccumulator
  }
  val rowsMargin = jtable.getRowMargin() * (jtable.getRowCount() - 1)
  println("Actual height " + jtable.getHeight())
  println("Header height " + headerHeight)
  println("Margin height " + jtable.getRowMargin())
  println("PreferredScrollableViewportSize" + jtable.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize())
  println("Rows height " + rowsHeight)
  println("Should be at least: " + (rowsHeight + headerHeight + rowsMargin))
```

and I got

```
Row 0 height 16
Row 1 height 16
Row 2 height 16
Row 3 height 16
Row 4 height 16
Actual height 80
Header height 19
Margin height 1
PreferredScrollableViewportSizejava.awt.Dimension[width=450,height=400]
Rows height 80
Should be at least: 103
```

The JTable lays inside the frame without any scroll bars. It is fully visible and there is a lot of space bellow.

How? How `jtable.getHeight()` of fully visible table may returns height less then (rows * rowHeight + header)?

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: I have not interest to show or hide a scroll bar. I have no interest to change table height. I just want to find the actual table height. At this time I think that `getHeight()` isn't include header height and `getRowMargin()` information.

Comment: This is one of unit tests from the huge project. I am sure that I am unable to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with acceptable efforts.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the test case rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute your own implementation of [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable) to get a variety of effects. In particular, override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` and return a suitable multiple of the row height. Let `N` be the number of rows after which you want the scrollbar to appear.

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel) {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(SOME_WIDTH, N * table.getRowHeight());
    }
};
```

Add the table to a scroll pane:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Add the pane to a panel having a layout that respects preferred size:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
p.add(sp);
```

A table having more than `N` rows will display scroll bars, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).

> I just want to find the actual table height [in the context of] unit tests from the huge project.

I don't know exactly how your total height calculation fails, but the result will inevitably change based on the user's platform, the chosen look & feel, and the component validation state; an erroneous approach is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513). Instead, attempt to meet the test requirement by ensuring that a paricular number of *rows* is visible using the approach outlined above.

Comment: (1+) for complete control over the tables initial size. Although I believe you also need to add in the height of the row header.

Comment: @camickr: Good point, but it looks like `headerHeight` is included; I think the test should be for visible _rows_, rather than visible _pixels_, but I'm spoiled by being allowed to propose derived requirements.

Answer (score 3):

> How? How jtable.getHeight() of fully visible table may returns height less then (rows * rowHeight + header)?

A JTable has a default preferred size that is hardcoded when the table is created because a table is typically added to the viewport of a JScrollPane. As you can see the preferred viewport size is much larger that you need for a small table which would account for the extra space.

If you have a small table and you want it to be fully displayed at it minimum size then you can use code like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```