# JTable won't dynamically add rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I've got a jtable which is supposed to add the fields from the Jtextfields to the table, the table exists on the pane as desired (columns names appear and no rows) but when I click to add a new row it adds a blank column instead (and only once)

The method which creates my table

```
public void createTable(){
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);       
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    tablepanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
```

And the button I use to add the data

```
class AddHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==btnUpload)
            {

                String nameRow = txtName.getText();
                String surnameRow = txtSurname.getText();
                String phoneRow = txtPhone.getText();
                String addressRow = txtAddress.getText();
                String postcodeRow = txtPostcode.getText();
                String emailRow = txtEmail.getText();
                Object[] row = {nameRow,surnameRow,phoneRow,addressRow,postcodeRow,emailRow};
                model.addRow(row);

            }

        }
    }
```

I have the default model set as a global variable like this:

```
private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: `Any suggestions are appreciated` - Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. So you create a frame with a JTable and an "Add Row" button. The add row button will simply add a row of hard coded data to the table. Then once you get that working you get the data dynamically from the text fields on your frame. If you have a problem with the SSCCE then you have code that we can compile and test to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be due to setting the scroll pane's size to 0. You should delete `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize())` or set a preferred size of your table by `table.setPreferredSize()` before you use `table.getPreferredSize()`.

Comment: Thank you, very simple solution that went over my head!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to invoking `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`, consider overriding the table's implementation  of `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` and making the height a multiple of `getRowHeight()`; a compete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel) {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, table.getRowHeight() * N);
    }
};
```

[image]

You can learn more about the `Scrollable` interface in [*Implementing a Scrolling-Savvy Client*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable).