# Unable to change location and size of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, layout-manager

I'm making a `JTable` in Java.

Here is my code. I have put the table on a panel (`jtjp1`), `jtjp1` is put on `adminjp1`.
`adminjp1` is put on `adminjf1`

### Code

```
 package Hotel_room_reservation_system;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Hotel_room_reservation_system extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public JFrame adminjf1;
public JTable jt1;
public JPanel adminjp1;
public JPanel jtjp1; 

public Hotel_room_reservation_system() {
    guimake();
}

public void guimake() {
   adminjf1 = new JFrame("ADMIN");

   adminjp1 = new JPanel();
   jtjp1 =new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   jt1=new JTable();
   String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "Gender"};

   String[][] data = {{"John", "18", "Male"},
                     {"Daisy", "19", "Female"},
                     {"Dave", "23", "Male"},
                     {"Jake", "30", "Male"}};

   jt1 = new JTable(data, columns)                 
   {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns)
        {
           return false;
        }


        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns)
        {
               Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);

               if ((data % 2 == 0))
                   c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

               else
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

               return c;
        }
    };



    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt1);
    //   jt1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jt1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jtjp1.setLocation(10,10);

    adminjf1.setSize(900, 900);
    adminjf1.setLayout(null);
    adminjp1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    adminjp1.setSize(800, 800);
    jtjp1.setSize(550,180);
    jtjp1.setBackground(Color.red);


    adminjp1.setLocation(20, 25); 
    jtjp1.add(jps);
    adminjp1.add(jtjp1);
    adminjf1.add(adminjp1);
    adminjf1.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Hotel_room_reservation_system();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }
 }
```

### Problems

1. I'm not able to move the size of the panel named `jtjp1`.
2. I'm not able to change location of `jtjp1` to the left or down. I have put `jtjp1` on `adminjp1`.

Comment: Don't use a `null` layout, instead let the [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to determine the size of the components. See [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: To expand on the comment of @Frakcool. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Other tips: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to establish a minimum row count, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the table component is not resizing is that you set a so called null layout manager with the `setLayout(null)`. Setting this means that you should take care of locating and resizing components in your GUI. 
This is what the layout managers do.

Once you use a layout manager, such as `GroupLayout`, the example works as
expected.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class HotelReservationSystemEx extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;

    public HotelReservationSystemEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "Gender"};

        String[][] data = {{"John", "18", "Male"},
        {"Daisy", "19", "Female"},
        {"Dave", "23", "Male"},
        {"Jake", "30", "Male"}};

        table = new JTable(data, columns) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);

                if ((data % 2 == 0)) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }

                return c;
            }
        };

        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(table);

        createLayout(spane);

        setTitle("Hotel reservation system");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            HotelReservationSystemEx ex = new HotelReservationSystemEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

In addition, you are unnecessary creating a `JPanel` and instantiating
the `JTable` twice.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from the example]

Comment: THNX MAN tysm! so much ty