# How to Print formatted JTable in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I am printing JTable as below.

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("My Header");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("My Footer {0,number,integer}");
table1.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, header, footer);
```

It is working but issue is it splits single table into two parts as my table is having many columns.  See Screenshot.

Image 1: Table in my application
[image: JSwing Table]

Image 2: Print Preview - Table is splitted into two parts.
[image: Print Preview]

Can anyone please help me in formatting table properly in Print Preview.

Also in description column some text are not appearing as there are many words in that field.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660448/table-print-does-not-fit-to-page-size/26665276#26665276) can help

Comment: You could also try using [`JTable#PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.PrintMode.html#FIT_WIDTH) or print in landscape mode

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer , it worked!!! but still problem is with description field. It is not showing entire description.

Comment: In the example I linked, one of the solutions is to resize the columns.  You could resize the columns to fit the content before printing. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126651/how-to-auto-resize-all-columns-of-a-jtable-to-the-same-size/15127241#15127241) for example...

Comment: use JLabels instead of MessageFormat header/footer

Answer (score 0):

TRY FIT_WIDTH INSTEAD OF  USING NORMAL.

Comment: Hello, please read [Why is it considered inappropriate and unprofessional to type in all capital letters?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-inappropriate-and-unprofessional-to-type-in-all-capital-letters). Thank you.